# Batch program to display files with complete directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc, batch-file, dos, msdn

I want to store the URL of all files with same extension in specific directory to one Log file. IS there any batch command available for this.

Exapmle
I want to copy all files with *.TXT extension into one log file with its directory extension(URL)

Answer (score 1):

you could use:

```
for /f %a in ('dir /b *.TXT') do echo %~fsa >> myLog.txt
```

note that the `>>` will append to the file, or create one if one does not exist.  This works well for a one-off, but you will want to properly initialize the file if you are running this often.

Answer (score 0):

Could use the `TREE` command available by the Command Prompt http://www.easydos.com/tree.html however you can't limit it by what type of files it lists.

Answer (score 0):

```
dir /a /s /b "DIRECTORY\*.txt" >logfile.log
```

/s is the trick with complete path, BUT includes subfolders to.